# как расставить запятые в этом предложении? "Однако в наивысшем смысле он вечно пребывает в нас как свет жизни"

Tags: пунктуация

"Однако в наивысшем смысле он вечно пребывает в нас как свет жизни"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как расставить запятые в этом предложении?
>
> "Однако в наивысшем смысле он вечно пребывает в нас как свет жизни"

Запятые не нужны. Нужна точка в конце предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Такие предложения требуют анализа и объяснения знаков препинания.

Желателен контекст, чтобы установить, тождество это или сравнение.

1) Допустим, что это сравнительный оборот (он как свет жизни), который не обособляется при тесной связи со сказуемым или в роли обстоятельства. В нашем случае это необособленное обстоятельство в конце предложения, на которое падает логическое ударение: "Однако в наивысшем смысле он вечно пребывает в нас как свет жизни".

При изменении позиции оборот будет обособлен:"Однако в наивысшем смысле он, как свет жизни,  вечно пребывает в нас ".

2) Допустим, что это тождество (он - это свет жизни). Тогда оборот не обособляется со значением "в качестве". Обособление со значением причины возможно при перестройке предложения:"Как свет жизни,  он вечно пребывает в нас".

Comment: _Vera: Желателен контекст, **чтобы установить, тождество это или сравнение**._ === Vera, А почему Вы не привели пример контекста, в котором этот оборот  **в приведённом в вопросе** предложении  следовало бы обособить? Или всё же контекст не важен? Ведь из дальнейших Ваших рассуждений вроде бы следует, что и **при сравнении, и при тождестве**  Вы считаете запятые ненужными. === **P.S.** А при изменении позиции оборота это будет ведь совсем другое предложение, а не то, о котором шла речь в вопросе.

Comment: Да, здесь нет обособления, но надо же объяснить синтаксическую роль оборота. Смысл предложения без контекста не очень ясен, поэтому это может быть сравнительный оборот в роли обстоятельств или  оборот со значением "в качестве".  Всё-таки краткий ответ  "запятые не нужны" может показаться автору недостаточно убедительным.

Comment: Да, я тоже перестраивала предложение. Все же, здесь имеет место необособленное обстоятельство. Благодарю за подробный анализ.